# How to filter array of dictionaries using nspredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am having an array of dictionaries with keys "name", "image", "email" and "phone" as keys. I want to filter the dictionaries containing email and phones separately using nspredicate, passing the dictionary key as search string. How can I achieve this.

Comment: this is requirements .. where is your attempt???

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to predicate multiple key or single key

Comment: This is how I am doing,

Answer (score 1):

Use NSPredicate class to filter your array of dictionary by specified key,

**For filter by email:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email contains[c] %@",strSearchString];

filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [[arrayData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy]];
```

**For filter by phone:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone contains[c] %@",strSearchString];

filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [[arrayData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy]];
```

Comment: why the [c] after "contains"?

Comment: for case insensitivity

Comment: and if you don't want it to be sensitive, just don't add [c] right? by definition its not case sensitive?

Comment: Columns in NSPredicateFormat are indexed to improve performance of using IN operators

[c] case insensitive: lowercase & uppercase values are treated the same

[d] diacritic insensitive: special characters treated as the base character